# Reference variable within a variable in JMeter

Tags: variables, jmeter

I have a User Defined Variable which generates random value

```
hashtagnumber ${__Random(1,5,)}
```

I have another set of user defined variables

```
hashtag1 #xxx #yyy #zzz
hashtag2 #aaa #bbb #ccc
```

I am trying to evaulate using below expression

${__eval(${hashtag}${hashtagnumber})} where I am expecting to generate unique hash tags for each iteration.

But I am getting below output.

```
GET http://${hashtag}3/
```

How to get unique hashtags using eval expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using below expression.

```
${__V(hashtag${hashtagnumber})}
```